# Проблема с обращением к переменной другого класса через метод

Tags: java, gui

Столкнулся с проблемой, камушками не бросайтесь пожалуйста. Есть два класса Home

```
public class home {

    private JFrame frame;
    panel12 fg;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    home window = new home();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public home() {
        initialize();
    }


    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new panel12();
        panel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        panel.setBounds(164, 34, 215, 182);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(22, 49, 89, 23);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource().equals(btnNewButton)){
                    fg.setSw(3);
                    fg.repaint();// перерисовка графика функции
                }
                    }
                });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);


    }
}
```

и panel12

```
public class panel12 extends JPanel {
private int sw=1;
public void paint(Graphics g){
super.paint(g);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drowLine(sw, sw, sw+100, sw+100)

public int getSw() {
      return sw;
     }

public void setSw(int sw) {
    this.sw = sw;
     }
}
```

Проблема в том что при обращении через метод `fg.setSw(3)` программа выдает ошибку. Ищу в чем проблема уже неделю. Если кто-либо видит в чем проблема (кроме горе-программиста) тыкните пальцем.

Comment: Какую ошибку хоть выдает?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at getset.home$2.actionPerformed(home.java:59)

Comment: panel12 fg не инициализированна(null)

Comment: Как же не инициализирована, если она объявлена сразу послеp rivate JFrame frame;

Comment: panel12 fg = new panel12(); //инициализация

Comment: Сделал. Vlad Vetrov подтолкнул. Заменил  'JPanel panel = new panel12();' на 'panel12 fg = new panel12();'  и заменил все 'panel' на объект 'fg'

Comment: Потому что у вас было 2 панели одна из которых равна null и к ней вы обращались, и вместо инициализации fg вы инициализировали другую ссылку - panel